# java invoice print CommPortIdentifier with unsigned bytes issue

Tags: java, printing, byte, unsigned, invoice

Hey,
I need to print invoices in a thermal invoice printer 
I wrote this program to do just that (see below)
However, for localization reasons I need send to the printer characters with values range of 0x80 – 0x102 , but I find it impossible since I cannot send a byte with this values (this are unsigned bytes which do not exist in java)

Any ideas on how to add this values to a string that will be sent to the printer ???
Thanks

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.NoSuchPortException;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class SimpleWrite {
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static OutputStream outputStream;

        public static void print(String messageString){
        try {
            portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier( "COM1");
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWrite", 2000);
            outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams( 9600,
                                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
            serialPort.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch (PortInUseException e) {                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch (NoSuchPortException e) {                System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        print("Hello , world \n\r");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can sent a byte with the hex value `0x80`.

The value ranges for `byte` in Java is:

```
-128 .. 127   (in decimal)
0x00 .. 0xff  (in hexadecimal)
```

You can send values in hex notation with the `\u` escape, like:

```
print("\u0080");   // sends 0x80 to your thermal printer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write such a character in your source using a Unicode escape, like

```
print("Eighty: \u0080\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to do the trick .. i get the letter i wanted, but with a supplement of a second letter due to the length variation of the unsigned byte type and the and the Unicode length

Comment: Your function is using getBytes() to get the data out of the String, taking the default encoding, which is apparently multibyte for the characters you're interested in. You should use the version of getBytes() that takes an encoding name, and use something that correctly encodes those characters -- i.e., `ISO-8859-1` .

Comment: Hey, thanks Ernest, however it seems that the plot thicks, the printer I m using has proprietary char-set. so as I see it I need to do one of the two, either send an ascii rather than unicode (I could not find a way to do so) or to implement the new charset (in which case I could use some help :-) ) , any ideas  (p.s. I really appreciate your help , thank a lot :-) )

Comment: Ultimately you just have to figure out exactly what bytes the printer wants to see, and send them. Read all the documentation you can, and good luck.